# How do you cross rivers?

Tags: towns

How do you cross rivers? I've seen [YouTube videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ro8BkyltRMk#t=04m20s) of people creating bridges to cross a river, but I don't see an option to build bridges in this version of the game.

On some random maps, a river will completely bisect a map. So is there some other way to cross rivers now, or are we stuck to one half of the map? (Towns has received quite a few updates recently, so this question pertains to the latest (as of right now) Steam version 13a.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to just build a small section of wall blocks at level 1 over it; townies can walk up onto those blocks, and get across to the other side. If you use Scaffolds, it's basically free (just costs a few moments' time, no materials), and easy to set up.

Comment: Hooray! That works. It's a bit tricky to place, and the blocks have a red X on them, but whatever. They still cross!